# Emacs regex: any characters spanning multiple lines between matching pattern

Tags: regex, emacs

I want to find `I - <characters> I -` and replace it with `I - <characters>, I -`.

The `<characters>` can be anything including Tab, Newline, Whitespace, *, & etc.

For example: `I - John M. Smith I -` Should be replaced with `I - John M. Smith, I -`.

I tried something like:

```
M-x Query replace regexp
\(I - \)\([a-z]+\) \(I - \)
\1\2, \3
```

It is not working. Can you please help?

Comment: FYI: You can use `M-x regex-builder` to build the regex interactively, or use regex101.com for a bit more help

Comment: Correction: `M-x regexp-builder`

Comment: Indeed `regexp-builder` can be very helpful.  For query/replace, I prefer using Isearch followed by <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>, so you also get to see incrementally the thing that is matched (but not the subgroups, admittedly).  E.g. doing the following: `C-u C-s \(I - \)\([a-z]+\) \(I - \) C-M-% \1\2, \3 RET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be made to work with a few adjustments to the regex.

### Input

```
I - abc I - 
I - defgh I - 
I - John M. Smith I - 
I - 1234567 I - 
I - 12345
67 I - 
I - 12345
6789ABC
DE F G H IJK
LM N O P I -
```

### Command

```
M-x query-replace-regexp
\(I - \)\(\(.*?
\)*?.*?\)\( I - \)
\1\2,\4
```

Note that the match regex in the above is really more like this...

```
\(I - \)\(\(.*?\n\)*?.*?\)\( I - \)
```

...with the `\n` representing the newline.  In the minibuffer, you would need to enter the `\n` as `C-q C-j`.

### Output

```
I - abc, I - 
I - defgh, I - 
I - John M. Smith, I - 
I - 1234567, I - 
I - 12345
67, I - 
I - 12345
6789ABC
DE F G H IJK
LM N O P, I -
```

### Explanation

Your original regex matched on character class `[a-z]+` in the middle.  However, you also said:

> The  can be anything including Tab, Newline, Whitespace, *, & etc.

To support that, we can change to `.*` to match any character.  However, this would risk consuming too much of the input, so we use the `?` for a lazy match.  The last tricky bit is multi-line matching, since you said there could be newlines.  To support that, we add the `\n` handling.

Looking at just the middle portion, we have...

```
\(\(.*?\n\)*?.*?\)
```

...and you can read this as "match on any number of characters (lazily) followed by newline any number of times (lazily), followed once again by any number of characters (lazily so as not to consume into the trailing `I -` portion of the lines).

### References

- [GNU Emacs Manual 15.10.2: Regexp Replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html)
- [Emacs Wiki Multiline Regexp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultilineRegexp)

Comment: You can simplify this to: `\(I - \(?:.\|^J\)*?\)\( I -\)` -> `\1,\2` (where the `^J` represents the newline, which should be typed as `C-q C-j` as previously mentioned. Note that `\(?: … \)` is a non-capturing group, which is why the `\2` is not `\3`.)